# findViewById (int) in Activity cannot be applied to (int, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

So I have been following [Slidnerd tutorial on the Navigation Drawer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR2K_Sav7q8&index=7&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD). The problem arises when I'm trying to create an instance of ActionBarDrawerToggle to specify the `Activity`, the `DrawerLayout` and the `Toolbar`.

```
(NavigationDrawerFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_nav_drawer); 
drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById (R.id.drawer_layout, toolbar);
```

I'm getting an error underlying the **(R.id.drawer_layout, toolbar)**. The error says:**" findViewById (int) in Activity cannot be applied to (int, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar"**.

I tried a suggested solution which was to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment but even after trying this the problem still persists, I even tried the vice versa. I'm also willing to post my relevant code if requested.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

All help is appreciated. Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because `findViewById` only takes an int, and not an int and a `Toolbar`. It should be used like this:

```
drawerFragment.setup((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```

Comment: @PolycapNyakundi - I have updated my code to show the full line.

Comment: Great. Since it worked if you could make it as correct that would be great. Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

just replace your line with this and the error is gone....

```
 drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```